# How to get a symbol image into a static shortcut menu item?

Tags: ios, shortcut, ios13

In the *Info.plist* UIApplicationShortcutItems entry:

- I can use `UIApplicationShortcutItemIconFile` to specify an image file name, corresponding to UIApplicationShortcutIcon `init(templateImageName:)`.
- I can use `UIApplicationShortcutItemIconType` to specify a system icon, corresponding to UIApplicationShortcutIcon `init(type:)`.

What *Info.plist* entry corresponds to `init(systemImageName:)`? How do I get a symbol image into the menu?